# Open access 7T resting-state fMRI dataset

Tags: neuroimaging, fmri

I'm looking for an open access dataset of 7-tesla resting state fMRI images of human subjects. I've been able to find one so far (http://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201454). However, I need images that were acquired using MP-RAGE (not MP2-RAGE) sequencing. I've checked the major open neuroscience repos so far with no luck. Does anyone know of an open access dataset that meets this description?

Answer (score 5):

There two 7 Tesla data sets currently publicly available, bith within the **OpenfMRI data collection**

[Here is a link](https://openfmri.org/dataset/ds000113/) to a 350 GB data set for 20 subjects watching the audio version of Forrest Gump. The authors also have all the scripts available at Github to enable reproduction. The associate publication can be found [here](http://www.nature.com/articles/sdata20143).

The other 7T data set you allready mentioned in your question. As far as I know there are only these two as of June 2016.

Answer (score 2):

The Nighres project has released some 7T MRI datasets and tools to run them. You can read the paper on the tools [here](https://doi.org/10.1093/gigascience/giy082), and download the datasets from [NITRC here](https://www.nitrc.org/frs/?group_id=1205).